# What applications can make use of the Kerberos Protocol?

Tags: network-programming, protocols

Does anyone know what sort of applications make use of the Kerberos protocol?

Is the Kerberos protocol still used? or is it considered old hat?

Cheers, 
Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Windows 2000 and later use Kerberos as their default authentication method.
>
> —[*Wikipedia: Kerberos (protocol)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol))